# Coupled degenerate wave equation and heat equation via transmission with Gurtin-Pipkin or Coleman-Gurtin thermal law

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, temperature, thermoelectricity

I am a mathematician and I am working on studying the stability of coupled degenerate wave equation and heat equation under with Gurtin-Pipkin or Coleman-Gurtin thermal law.
The classic wave equation is $u_{tt}-u_{xx}=0$.
My study is working with the degenerate wave equation: $u_{tt}-a(x)u_{xx}=0$ where $a$ is a function such that $a>0$ on $(0,1]$, $a(0)=0$. 
And the heat equation for both (Gurtin-Pipkin if m=1) or (Coleman-Gurtin if 0<m<1)  : $y_t-c(1-m)y_{xx}-cm\int_{0}^{\infty}g(s)y_{xx}(x,t-s)ds=0$
and couple these two equation by using some transmission conditions.

My questions are:

1. What is the physical significance of considering the degenerate wave equation instead of w
2. What is the physical significance of studying the coupled wave and heat equation of type (Gurtin-Pipkin) or (Coleman-Gurtin). If you can give an example of this.

thank you in advance

Comment: 1. what is "w"? 2. see section V here https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Luigi-Preziosi/publication/265053093_heatwaves/links/53fd85d50cf2364ccc08c95f/heatwaves.pdf In classical Fourier conduction heat propagates instantaneously, there are several models starting with Cattaneo to incorporate, that is forcing, finite propagation velocity  into conduction phenomenon; see Joseph & Preziosi for several of these models, one is by Gurtin-Pipkin. To understand Gurtin-Pipkin you need some background in the so-called "*rational thermodynamics*" of Truesdell, Coleman, Noll.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 1. What is the physical significance of considering the degenerate wave equation instead of classical wave equation.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "degenerate wave equation". Fourier's law of conduction is not a wave equation and it is "bad physics" because it implies that any change in temperature anywhere is immediately felt everywhere.

Comment: Degenerate wave equation is the wave equation of the form $u_{tt}−a(x)u_{xx}=0$ but with the function $a$ strictly positive and vanishes at $0$. \\ I just want to know the difference physically. Here is a mathematical paper that studies the degenerate wave equation (if you want to now what I mean)  http://dx.doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2212.05264 . Appreciate your response.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know anything about that.